# Date field not saving in proper format while saving in XSSFWorkbook

Tags: excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

I'm trying to save list of user defined object in excel i.e .xlsx format from a REST API. which creates a **XSSFWorkbook** and stores the data in workbook. returns **ByteArrayInputStream**. In my Entity class i'm storing it as

`@Column(name = "created_date", columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date createdDate;`

> Here is piece of code for writing list to Workbook in service.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();     
    // Create a blank sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Survey");
    String[] columns = {"Name","createdDate"};
     ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int rownum = 1;
    for (Integer key : keyset) {
        // this creates a new row in the sheet
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Survey survey = data.get(key);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(survey.getName());
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(survey.getCreatedDate());
    }
    try {           
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        workbook.close();
    }
return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

In the controller i'm setting the header `contentType` and `content-disposition` and returning as **ResponseEntity**.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
 headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "AuditTrial.xlsx");
return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(isr);
```

Actual data is given below, i.e data coming from the database

`[{
"createdDate": "2019-07-15T07:45:48.555Z",
 "name": "abc"
 },{
 "createdDate": "2019-07-15T07:45:48.555Z",
 "name": "xyz" }]`

problem is when i tried to open excel which will be produced after calling the above api,the date format is not proper. it is as below.

[image]

How to save the date in proper format in excel ? where i'm getting it wrong. Any helps and suggestions welcomed.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter it's worked after setting CellStyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entity is not related to apache poi's cell.
In your entity's createdDate you are setting that it is a timestamp but it tells nothing to apache poi.

When you want to create a date cell you need to:

- create a CellStyle
- set date format for that CellStyle
- apply that CellStyle to the desired Cell(s)

For example:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
```

...

```
for (Integer key : keyset) {
    // this creates a new row in the sheet
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    Survey survey = data.get(key);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(survey.getName());
    Cell dateCell = row.createCell(1);
    dateCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    dateCell.setCellValue(survey.getCreatedDate());
}
```

Comment: if you are exporting from the database you might consider using my library MemPOI to avoid such problems https://github.com/firegloves/MemPOI